# mysql_query error even though syntax of query is correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "my_ales****";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbuser = "ales***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die("sukotto");

if ($_POST["invia_ricerca"]){
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $query = " SELECT gruppo1 FROM elenco WHERE nome = '$nome' ";
    $risultato = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("suka");
    echo $risultato;
}
```

If I write the query into phpmyadmin page it works. If I try to launch the query using mysql_query it doesn't work and print "suka" (die()). And if I try `mysql_error()` into die(), Nothing prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$host       = "localhost";
$dbname     = "my_ales****";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbuser     = "ales***";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die("sukotto");

//  Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL
if ( isset($_POST["invia_ricerca"]) )
{
    // Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL
    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["nome"]);

    // Prepare Query
    $query = sprintf("SELECT gruppo1 FROM elenco WHERE nome = '%s'", $nome);

    // Performs a query on the database
    $risultato = mysqli_query($query, $conn) or die( mysqli_error($conn) );

    // Fetch a result row 
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato) ) 
    {
        printf("<p>%s</p>", $row['gruppo1']);
    }

    // Free result
    mysqli_free_result($risultato)
}
```

PS. die("suka") è fantastico ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are using mysqli_* functions for connection but in query you are using mysql_query. 
it should by mysqli_query

change this

```
$risultato = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("suka");
```

to

```
$risultato = mysqli_query($query, $conn) or die("suka");
```

=========== Edit====

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "my_ales****";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbuser = "ales***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die("sukotto");

if ($_POST["invia_ricerca"]){
   $nome = $_POST["nome"];
   $query = " SELECT gruppo1 FROM elenco WHERE nome = '$nome' ";
   $risultato = mysqli_query($query, $conn) or die("suka");
   $row = $risultato->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
   printf ("%s\n", $row[0]);  //use %i for integer

}
```

Comment: Or try to use mysqli over mysql, since it is deprecated.

Comment: I try to use mysqli_query($conn, $query) but the return is different and when i try to print it, echo returns an error (can't convert $risultato in a string).

Comment: do a print_r($risultato) as returned is an array. for echoing values im posting code below

Comment: for printing values use this code: $row = $risultato->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s \n", $row[0]);

Answer (score 0):

You have missed up mysqli with mysql. Try this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "my_ales****";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbuser = "ales***";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die("sukotto");

if ($_POST["invia_ricerca"]){
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$query = " SELECT gruppo1 FROM elenco WHERE nome = '$nome' ";
$risultato = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("suka");
if ($risultato) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risultato)) {
   print_r($row);   
  }
 mysqli_free_result($risultato);
}
}
```

Comment: @alessandro308: did you try this?